# Unable to connect sql server database with codeigniter on xampp with windows 7

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have an application where i need to connect my web (PHP based) application with desktop application database so that both desktop and web can communicate with each other.
On ubuntu OS connectivity is working fine but when i comes to windows 7 codeigniter sql server connectivity is not working.
i tried visual c++ redistributional packages as well as other instructions provided on many platforms but fails.
i also added extensions in php\ext and dll files as well as include that extensions like sql_serv55_nts like that but nothing is working.
last error that i am receiving is

> application not be run as php5.dll is missing .
>   can some one help to figure this out as soon as possible and can send me proper tested procedure for this.

Comment: Have you installed [`Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Comment: no i did not tried this.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should be using the `Thread Safe` versions of the SQLServer libraries. Apache on windows is normally run as a Thread Safe configuration. WAMPServer and XAMPP(Windows) run  Thread Safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you have installed the `sql_serv55_nts` version of the SQLServer libraries, this is your problem.

Instead install the TS (Thread Safe) version of the SQLServer libraries. XAMPP on windows runs Thread Safe.

The `php5.dll` is the `Non Thread Safe` version of `php5ts.dll` which is supplied with the XAMPP install of PHP.

> Once you install the TS version of SQLServer libraries delete the `php5.dll` it is not required, also you got it from a source that you cannot be sure is safe. A **simple rule of thumb** If it was required it would have come with the XAMPP install.
>
> NOTE: You should never need to copy anything related to Apache/PHP/MYSQL into the Windows system folders. If you do, when you come to install another version of XAMPP it will still be there and will cause you hours of debugging to find out why you are having odd issues.
>
> ALSO: It is also dangerous adding anything XAMPP or WAMPServer related to the Windows PATH as this will also cause you issues when you come to update XAMPP/WAMPServer as you are bound to forget that this was done.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your php directory and your php extensions directory to your PATH environment variables.

Comment: Or better still Dont add it to your PATH

Comment: How are you executing your code on Windows - wamp, xamp, ...? Please explain your windows php and database setup in more detail

Comment: XAMPP(Windows) runs in thread safe mode. The error is that you have installed the NTS version of the SQLServer libraries

Answer (score -1):

I resolved issue in following way.

1. Install xampp with php 5.5
2. install microsoft re distributional package
3. download php5.ddl file from [php5.dll](http://originaldll.com/file/php5.dll/30704.html)
4. if window is 32 bit than just copy downloaded php5.dll into windows/system32
5. if you have 64bit window than you need to copy it into windows/SysWOW64 too.
   best is to restart your PC
   All done......

Comment: **You should NEVER need to copy PHP dll files to your ` windows/system32` or `windows/SysWOW64`** in a correctly configured WAMP or XAMPP. It will just cause you problems later when you upgrade PHP and forget that you copied this file there, and then you have a new set of issues.

Comment: No it is necessary. my xampp was properly configured but still it was giving  this error. when i copied this into described folders it works perfectly.

Comment: If its properly configure **it is not necessary**

Comment: As far as i remember `php5.dll` is used in a `not thread safe` configuration. I dont have one in my WAMPServer installation, which runs `Thread Safe`. I thought XAMPP(Windows) also ran a `Thread Safe` config. Have you accidentally install a `NTS` version of something related to PHP.

Comment: Yes it looks like you did exactly that `sql_serv55_nts` try the `Thread Safe` version of the SQLServer libraries. Then get rid of the `php5.dll` completely

Comment: may be you are right but i share my problem solution. may it help to others if any one face issue

Comment: But you **and other people** would not have this problem if they install the CORRECT version of the SQLServer libraries for XAMPP i.e. the Thread Safe libraries